# Can we rank results of linear regression model using estimate, r-squared and p-value?

Tags: lm

Is there a way to rank the results of a linear model applied across thousands of values? For e.g. I have a table of 6004 rows, each corresponding to a gene and the corresponding output of linear regression model (I used the `lm` function in R):

```
      gene  estimate model.rSquared     p.value
1  Slc25a4 17.442867      0.1954532 0.001654828
2 Mettl21c 12.104128      0.1780214 0.002817559
3    Pvalb 11.449275      0.1242439 0.014005302
4    Mybph  9.789242      0.1061216 0.023853234
5    Actn3  9.736698      0.1454820 0.007476086
6   Mybpc2  9.637181      0.1031207 0.026049394
```

I wanted to know if I can somehow rank these values using the combination of p-value, r-squared and estimate (**absolute value of estimate** to be precise)? Currently I am using a very naive approach of sorting the results first by p-value (low -> high), then by correlation (high -> low) and then by abs(estimate) (high -> low).

Thanks